# Wake up from suspend does not show log in screen immediately

Tags: 14.04, suspend, wakeup

I have noticed that when I wake up my computer from "suspend", the log in screen does not appear immediately. Instead, the image of the screen before I initiated "suspend" appears for a second or two.
I find this a little annoying since if someone "wake up" my suspended computer, they can see what I am doing on the screen.

This does not seem to happen only to my current computer as it happens on my older computer also (with the same version of Ubuntu (14.04)). Both those computers are laptops.

I could not find anything regarding this problem anywhere. Am I just unfortunate to have this problem on the two computers, or does anyone else have this problem to?

And last but not least; does anyone have a solution/fix for this "bug"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1280300).

I would recommend to sign up at Launchpad and add yourself to the people that this bug affects. It is a bit worrying that nothing has been done about this bug, a clear security issue, for over a year.

Comment: I see. Indeed a great concern regarding security. I better check bugs at launchpad on forehand before posting "bugs" here. Thank you for your answer Jos.

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, please mark it as such by clicking the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: The bug you are refering to has been marked invalid.

Comment: does it affect 17.04?  I personally haven't witnessed it.

Comment: I am not sure for 17.04, but I am currently running 16.04 with gnome. And I don't have the problem.